# Closed set of irrationals with non zero outer measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let  $A$ be the set of irrationals in $[0,1]$, then for every $\epsilon >0$ how we can construct a closed subset $B$ of $A$ such that outer measure $\mu^{*}$ of $B$ satisfies :

$\mu^{*}(B) \ge 1- \epsilon$.

I know that every finite set is closed but that will not work here, somehow I need to construct a set of some special kind of irrationals such that above property is satisfied. I am not able to think the type of set that will work here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is not to think of what we want to incude, rather of what we want to exclude.

Hint: enumerate the rationals in $[0,1]$ as $r_n$, $n = 1,2,3,\ldots$.  Let $B = [0,1] \backslash \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (r_n - \epsilon_n, r_n + \epsilon_n)$ for a suitable sequence
$\epsilon_n$ of positive numbers.

Comment: ok, so here we need to choose $\epsilon_{n}$ in such a way that $\sum \epsilon_{n} < \epsilon$.